# Having trouble with Datasource & session cross reference in a multi URL application

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, tomcat6, jndi

I have an application which is configured to connect to a specific database as per the URL with their unique credentials-

eg -

1. demo.mydomain.com      (DB Name - demo)
2. client1.mydomain.com   (DB Name - client1)
3. client2.mydomain.com   (DB Name - client2)

I have defined the data source in context.xml in my web-inf dir as below -

```
<!-- demo Environment Configuration Starts  -->

<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            name="jdbc/demo" 
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo"
            username="demo" 
            password="demo" 
            initialSize="10"
            maxActive="100" 
            maxIdle="30" 
            minIdle="0"
            suspectTimeout="60"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
           />

<!-- Client1 Environment Configuration Starts   -->

<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            name="jdbc/client1" 
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/client1"
            username="client1" 
            password="client1" 
            initialSize="10"
            maxActive="100" 
            maxIdle="30" 
            minIdle="0"
            suspectTimeout="60"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
            />
```

The list goes on for all the available clients.

The SysServlet is defined in web.xml with a URL mapping -

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SysInfo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.emsproject.action.common.SysServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SysInfo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/eapp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

```
public class SysServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet{
static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static DataSource dataSource;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    try {
        String clientName = request.getPathInfo();
        String esmPool = clientName.substring(1, clientName.length()).trim();
        /******************************************************
         * Below code prepares the datasource by JNDI lookup * 
         ******************************************************/
        dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/"+esmPool);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*Returns a connection */
public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}

/*Closing connection when transaction is over*/
public void freeConnection(Connection dbConn) {
    try { 
        if(null != dbConn){
            dbConn.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The Application is built using -

1. Struts 2
2. MySql 5
3. Tomcat 6

The application works fine without any issue for a single client at a time but
the problems I am facing are as below -

1. When a client1 performs some insert/update it is reflected to client2 & so on when application is accessed simultaneously by them.
2. When a Client1 performs a login (I keep certain details in session) & later Client2 logs in to the system the Client2 info is shared or visible to client1.

Simultaneous access is troubling me 
Kindly suggest me a solution for the same ....

---

I have made few changes to the code as below while fetching a connection -

```
public Connection getConnection(String clientName) throws Exception {
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/"+clientName);
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}
```

But I have one concern regarding the statement -

```
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/"+clientName);
```

Is it ok to initialize a DataSource every time I need a connection...

Kindly suggest...

Answer (score 0):

You are not technically initializing a `DataSource` each time you need a connection.  You are looking up the `DataSource` in the JNDI context each time.  There will only ever be one instance of each `DataSource`.

The lookup is pretty fast (essentially just a map lookup) so I personally wouldn't worry too much.

What is going to be much much slower is creating the `InitialContext`.  The creation of `InitialContext()` is slow and should only be done once in your application and cached.

Comment: I tried couple of ways to create a InitialContext just once to use but I am unable to as it throws null pointer on the created object.I defined it as "Context ctx = null" & in doGet method I initialized it as "ctx  = new InitialContext()". But the ctx is null I am not sure how to configure it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your comment.  If you can list the code you are now using to try and cache the InitialContext it might help.

Answer (score 0):

@Pace

I am adding it as an answer to better format the code in the post I have modified,

The ctx throws a null pointer ........ (I have no idea about caching the InitialContext)

```
public class SysServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet{
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //Context ctx = null;
    InitialContext ctx = null;



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            String clientName = request.getPathInfo();
            String esmPool = clientName.substring(1, clientName.length()).trim();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*Returns a connection */
    public Connection getConnection(String clientName) throws Exception {
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup ("java:/comp/env/jdbc/"+clientName);
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }     
    /*Closing connection when transaction is over*/
    public void freeConnection(Connection dbConn) {
        try { 
            if(null != dbConn){
                dbConn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I need sugestions to avoid doing new InitialContext() on every getConnection();

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes to initialize the Context only once per login & this seems to be working fine....
Only had to change the

InitialContext ctx = null;

to

private static InitialContext ctx = null;

Answer (score 0):

Just construct the InitialContext during object construction of the Servlet:

```
public class SysServlet ....{
    private InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    ....
}
```

After that, you can do the look-up in the getConnection() and it should work.